# 人が何人います grammar construction

Tags: grammar

I have learned this sentence during a Japanese lesson

> 会議室に人が何人いますか。

I don't understand why there is double information about 人?
Why is it not just this form? and are there differences between these two forms?

> 会議室に何人いますか。

And is it ok to also say :

> 会議室に何人ですか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **double** information. 何人 is used for a counter - consider it a unit of measurement. You are responsible to attach the correct counter, but the **counter is not responsible to explain the subject**.

A. How many **kg** does that **weigh**? (subject + unit of measurement)

B. How many **kg** is it? (without subject)

Some may think A is too much (double) information. Some may think B is too less (few) information. Both are correct, neither is wrong.

---

- 会議室に人が何人いますか。
- 会議室に何人いますか。

They both make sense. Longer sentence is verbose and formal. Shorter sentence is lean and casual. Both are correct, neither is wrong.

---

> And is it ok to also say : 会議室に何人ですか。

No :( This one is a grammatical error. It should be:

"会議室に何人いますか" or "会議室にいるのは何人ですか".

---

The above is the answer considering your question:

> "is it ok to also **say**"

It would be different if we **write**. Because the kanji 何人 can mean:

- how **many** people

or

- what **nationality**

Considering that:

**会議室に [何人]{なにじん} がいますか**
In the meeting room, person of which nationality is there?

**会議室に [何人]{なんにん} いますか**
In the meeting room, how many number of people is there?