# Understanding "６人もの人"

Tags: translation

From the first episode of Death Note:

> えー 昨日 新宿(しんじゅく)の繁華街で**６人もの人を**殺傷した通り魔は今なお 幼児と保育士８人を人質に この保育園に立てこもっております

I'm trying to understand what's going on with the bolded portion "６人もの人を", which I'm assuming means "6 people". I'm assuming the first 人 is the people counter. So what is the もの and the second 人 doing after it?

Why isn't the phrase just

> ６人を

As it stands now, it sounds like the phrase means

> "(6 people things) people"

Comment: [Definition 4](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%82/#jn-218350) in this dictionary entry may help.

Comment: Do you understand ６人の人?

Comment: @istrasci I don't.

Comment: Related: [Why is 「の」 used in 何十もの？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56819/43676)

Comment: I've read up on counters and I think the answer to my question is: (i) の comes ６人 since the counter functions as a *noun* in this instance; (ii) the も comes before の in this instance though just to add emphasis to ６人 (i.e., "6 people(!) were murdered!").

Comment: This is also kind of related: [人が何人います grammar construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93486/43676)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not もの. It’s a combination of two particles, も and の.

> ６人**も**の人を殺傷した

も here indicates that the speaker considers the said number to be large, as explained in this [answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/56825/43676).

The following are both correct and neutral (meaning no emphasis) statements, though some might consider the latter a bit redundant.

> ６人を殺傷した

> ６人の人を殺傷した

The following is also correct, but it would sound a bit too subjective for something coming from a news reader.

> ６人も殺傷した